# OpenSSH/Git Problem under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh, git, openssh

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and am trying to clone a git repository via ssh. Unfortunately this does not work due to problems with openssh-client.

In the beginning I was unable to connect to the SSH Server. The following debug output was produced:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test.com [ommitted] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

After having uncommented the Ciphers and the MACs line in /etc/ssh/ssh_config as described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/174168. I am able to connect via ssh.

Unfortunately I am still unable to clone the repository via git using ssh:

```
jan@jan-ThinkPad-T510:~$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone   ssh://user@host/path/to/repo
trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'ssh://user@host/path/to/repo' Cloning into 'repo'...
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'user@host' 'git-upload-pack '\''/path/to/repo'\'''
```

Any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: `ssh://user@host/path/to/repo` should be `user@host:/path/to/repo`

Comment: shouldn't and doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured due to different MTU settings and a probably misconfigured firewall at my internet provider (KabelBW).

I solved the problem by setting the MTU to 576 via

```
ifconfig wlan0 mtu 576
```

Note that after setting the MTU, you have to disconnect and reconnect to the network. For further Details have a look at [Snailbook MTU Mismatch](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html)